# How can I split an input using multiple delimiters?

Tags: c, arrays, split

I want to split into tokens an lessons.txt file. This file has some people and these people's lessons. How can I do it ?

There is my lessons.txt file :

```
George Adam            :Math,Science,Germany
Elizabeth McCurry      :Music,Math,History
Tom Hans               :Science,Music
```

Firstly, I want to split into ":".  And I want to store names in an array. Secondly , I want to split into "," and these lessons I want to store an different array. How can I this ?

There is my code below :

```
char names[100] , *token, *lecture;

file=fopen("C:\\lessons.txt","r");
while(!feof(file))
{
    fgets(names,sizeof(names),file);
    printf("%s",names);
    token=strtok(names,":");

    while(token!=NULL)
    {
        token=strtok(NULL,":");
        printf(" \n %s",token); 
        lecture=strtok(token,",");
        while(lecture!=NULL)
        {
            lecture=strtok(NULL,",");
            printf(" \n\n %s",lecture);
        }   
    }
}

fclose(file);
```

Comment: [`while (!feof(f))` is **always wrong.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

Comment: Your second `strtok` for the `:` throws away the first result. (Other than that, you appear to be looking for the right thing. Use a debugger to fix any remaining issues.)

Comment: Also, `strtok()` has internal `static` state, and as such its state is implicit, and it's also inherently thread-unsafe. Hence it should not be used, and it should be replaced by `strtok_r()`.

Comment: Why is always wrong? @TheParamagneticCroissant

Comment: @Elminaa read the linked answer.

Answer (score 1):

So you want names to be stored in a separate array, and lessons to be stored in another?
You will need two separate tokens, you are using the same token for names and lessons.
Try this :

```
FILE *file;
file = fopen("C:\\lessons.txt", "r");
char names[100], *token, *difftok;
while (fgets(names, sizeof(names), file) != NULL) {
  token = strtok(names, ":")

  //puts(token); ---> George Adams

  difftok = strtok(NULL, ",");

  //puts(difftok); ---> Math

  difftok = strtok(NULL, ",");

  //puts(difftok);  ---> Science

  difftok = strtok(NULL, "\n");

  //puts(difftok);  ---> Germany
  }
  fclose(fp);
}
```

In my excerpt, token will always represent names, and difftok will always be lectures, from here I think you can figure out how to store the tokens into an array. Token goes into one, difftok into another.

Also, your EOF condition is wrong, feof returns a non-zero when it reaches end of file :

```
while(!feof(file))
```

Should be:

```
while(feof(file) ==  0)
```

However, in this case I used fgets(...) != NULL because fgets return NULL when it reached end of file. You should probably use my condition as feof(file) == 0 encounters some end of file problems when used with your code and messes up the way the tokens parse the string.

Comment: Thank you, I editede my code but there is a problem .  My input file is like                                                          George Adam            :Math,Science,Germany     and it has some null charceters .so , when I split my output has <null>

Comment: I don't use your exact code but my output has null and this is a problem. I must fix it . Thansk again

Comment: My input file has null characters

Comment: Unfortunately there is no easy way to skip the null characters, you probably need to edit the file to remove all null characters first, and then try your code.

Comment: char *tokenize(char array[]){
 char list[10];
 char *token,*subtoken;
 char *subtoken2,*subtoken3;
 token=strtok(array,":");
    subtoken = strtok(NULL, ",");
 subtoken2 = strtok(NULL, ",");
 subtoken3 = strtok(NULL, "\0");
 return subtoken3;
}

Comment: I'm confused, your subtoken3 seems to say that the line in the file ends with a "\0", right? This means it won't parse the string if it is not a null character.

Comment: I want to split all things in txt file. BU when I use your code I just have only the first sentence (George,math ,science,germany) But I want all of them .Can you have any advice ?

Comment: are you using the while loop I provided? Because the code works on my comp.

Comment: If you implemented the while loop, and it still does not work, re-edit the question and put in the new code that you have.